# Using HTML5 file input to select file from web server

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Is there anyway I could javascript or just modify the html5 file input tag to select files from my web server? this is a content management kind of problem so security is not an issue, and if possible i would like to restrict it to a particular directory in the web server. Am not trying to upload or download anything, I already have a way of uploading the files to the web server, am just looking for a way to point to them if you will.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change the browse path with javascript..

Like:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068156/server-side-file-browsing

Comment: The clientside can not see anything on the serverside. You need to build something that sends the data down to the client to render.

Comment: That's not possible with the native browser control. You should write your own.